# jquery qrcode fails using more than 34 char long

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, qr-code

I am using this jquery plugin to generate QR Codes from string:

https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode

It works fine with strings with less than 35 chars, if the string is 35 o bigger qrCode simply doesn't get displayed.

My strings are 95 chars long.

Is this a logical limitation ? am I using the wrong library?

Any ideas or reccomendations about this?

(my backend is python/django so any python based solutions would be acceptable too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a look at the github site, there is a closed issue that seems to relate to this: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode/issues/2

There appears to be a `typeNumber` property that can be changed upon creation. It appears that changing this from it's default of 4 to higher numbers (ie. 8 or so) increases the amount of characters available.

I'm not sure what the range of `typeNumber`s are, or what exactly it represents (possibly a bit depth or something), but try that out...

HTH

EDIT: I googled a bit, and it appears that the `typeNumber` refers to a kind of QRcode "version" of some description.

A full breakdown of the versions/`typeNumber`s can be found at: http://www.denso-wave.com/qrcode/vertable1-e.html

Comment: +1 You hit the nail on the head. See [my test here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pja4X/1/). It defaults to 4, as you said, and does _not_ automatically change based on provided data. It must be changed explicitly.